# Not receiving push notifications via gcm.js no matter app open or closed

Tags: php, android, titanium, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules

Yesterday I was trying to implement the notification on my Titanium Alloy App, when server php script is run.
Once it worked but don't know what happened thereafter no notification is coming on calling CURL request  on my PHP server. Response is coming after Calling CURL to Android GCM Send

```
Sample response: id=0:1431949527356415%1ba0f8cc00000030
```

I have checked everything.
1. My server IP is listed in Google API aproved server.
2. Project ID is same (GCM_sender_id)
3. Api key is same given by Google, 
4. Device token is correct

I wrote:

```
var gcm = require('net.iamyellow.gcmjs')

var pendingData = gcm.data;
if (pendingData && pendingData !== null) {
    // if we're here is because user has clicked on the notification
    // and we set extras for the intent 
    // and the app WAS NOT running
    // (don't worry, we'll see more of this later)
    Ti.API.info('******* data (started) ' + JSON.stringify(pendingData));
}

gcm.registerForPushNotifications({
    success: function (ev) {
        // on successful registration
        Ti.API.info('******* success, ' + ev.deviceToken);
    },
    error: function (ev) {
        // when an error occurs
        Ti.API.info('******* error, ' + ev.error);
    },
    callback: function () {
        // when a gcm notification is received WHEN the app IS IN FOREGROUND
        alert('hellow yellow!');
    },
    unregister: function (ev) {
        // on unregister 
        Ti.API.info('******* unregister, ' + ev.deviceToken);
    },
    data: function (data) {
        // if we're here is because user has clicked on the notification
        // and we set extras in the intent 
        // and the app WAS RUNNING (=> RESUMED)
        // (again don't worry, we'll see more of this later)
        Ti.API.info('******* data (resumed) ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```

The issue is, Device is generating token, i.e. goes to the **success** part, but is not coming now in **callback**

Please anyone knows the solution?

Comment: some stupid voted down. don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Ok, It was my wifi connection issue with maybe google sent url. I switched to 3G network and everything started working fine.